# how to increment counter value in different functions in shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell

i have 5 functions ..if one function works count value should be incremented  and that value should be given to next function

```
count=1
function1()
{
count++
}

function2(){
count++
}
```

Comment: And what is your question? Don't put it in the comments, edit the question.

Comment: i want to increment the value inside the function. in function1 my value is 2 and in function2 it should become 3 ..but it is taking the value count =1 and printing 2 in function2

Comment: Didn't I just say edit the question? You need to tell us what you expect and what happens instead, just like you did in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the `count++` syntax.

```
count=1

foo() {
count=$((count+1))
}


foo
foo
echo $count   # prints 3
```

Use `$((VAR))` syntax to perform numeric calculations on variable.

Comment: You can also write `((count++))` -- you can assign/modify variables within double parentheses.